# Generalizing Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem to Modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R = \mathbf{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and let $M$ be a graded $R$-module which is finite-dimensional over $\mathbf{C}$ and suppose
$
0 \leftarrow M \leftarrow R^g \leftarrow R^d \leftarrow \cdots
$
is a minimal resolution of $M$.  I believe that it follows that $d \geq gn$, but don't know how prove this, or derive it from standard results in commutative algebra.

The connection to Krull's PIT is that this theorem should cover the case $g = 1$.

Comment: I added a reference which might help with some positive answers. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R=k[x,y]$, $I$ be any height $2$ ideal with at least 3 generators. Then $I$ has a resolution:

$0 \to R^a \to R^b \to I \to 0$

Counting ranks gives $b=a+1$. Dualizing the above sequence, noting that $I^* =R$ ($^*$ denotes $Hom_R(-,R)$), we get:

$0\to R \to R^b \to R^a \to Ext_R^1(I,R) \to 0$

Let $M = Ext_R^1(I,R)$. Clearly $M = Ext_R^2(R/I,R)$, so it has finite length since $R/I$ has finite length. If your conjecture is true then $b\geq 2a =2(b-1)$. But that contradicts our choice of $I$ ($b\geq 3$, for concreteness $I= (x^2,xy,y^2)$ should work).

EDIT: of course, with additional assumptions one may have some hope. The key words to search for is "Horrocks's conjecture". For example, this [new paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0316) by Dan Erman might be helpful to you. Theorem 1.2 looks particularly relevant!

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply.

Concretely, if $I = (x^2,xy,y^2)$, then the constructed $M$ is the quotient of a free $R$-module on two generators $e$ and $f$ by the submodule generated by the 3 elements $xe, yf, ye-xf$.



Comment: Dear Dikran, no worries. I was just about to add the concrete description!  